# Making an HTTP request with a blank user agent

Tags: http, iis, user-agent

I'm troubleshooting an issue that I think may be related to request filtering. Specifically, it seems every connection to a site made with a blank user agent string is being shown a 403 error. I can generate other 403 errors on the server doing things like trying to browse a directory with no default document while directory browsing is turned off. I can also generate a 403 error by using a tool like Modify Headers for Google Chrome (Google Chrome extension) to set my user agent string to the Baidu spider string which I know has been blocked.

What I can't seem to do is generate a request with a BLANK user agent string to try that. The extensions I've looked at require something in that field. Is there a tool or method I can use to make a GET or POST request to a website with a blank user agent string?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend trying a CLI tool like cURL or a UI tool like Postman. You can carefully craft each header, parameter and value that you place in your HTTP request and trace fully the end to end request-response result.

This example straight from the [cURL docs on User Agents](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#User_Agent) shows you how you can play around with setting the user agent via cli.

```
curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.73 [en] (X11; U; Linux 2.2.15 i686)" [URL]
```

In postman its just as easy, just tinker with the headers and params as needed. You can also click the "code" link on the right hand side and view as HTTP when you want to see the resulting request.

You can also use a heap of hther HTTP tools such as Paw and Insomnia, all of which are quite well suited to your task at hand.

One last tip - in your chrome debugging tools, you can right click the specific request from the network tab and copy it as cURL. You can then paste your cURL command and modify as needed. In Postman you can import a request and past from raw text and Postman will interpret the cURL command for you which is particularly handy.